# I'm using Windows 10 and I can't seem to use set the environment variable on nodejs on my terminal

Tags: node.js

I'm a beginner to nodejs. I created two json files with different names and mail.host. The first one is called development.json

```
{
    "name": "My Express App - Development",
    "mail": {
        "host": "dev-mail-server"
    }
}
```

and the other one is production.json

```
{
    "name": "My Express App - Production",
    "mail": {
        "host": "prod-mail-server"
    }
}
```

after using executing this code below on my index.js, the terminal prints the same output even after using `set NODE_ENV="production"` in the terminal. What seems to be the problem in my code? Thank you so much!

```
console.log(`Application Name: ${config.get('name')}`)
console.log(`Mail Server: ${config.get('mail.host')}`)
```

Comment: What output do you get? Have you put the config files in the correct directory? The default is `./config/`

Comment: and what does `console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV)` print?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume you're using the [config](https://www.npmjs.com/package/config) package.
I've created an example app in Windows 10 to test all this using the below file structure. I suspect you just need to omit the quotes, e.g.

```
SET NODE_ENV=development
```

when you're setting the NODE_ENV variable.

Here's the app details:

**Folder Structure**

```
project
|  app.js
|
└──config
    | development.json
    | production.json
```

**app.js**

```
const config = require('config');
console.log(`Application Name: ${config.get('name')}`);
console.log(`Mail Server: ${config.get('mail.host')}`);
```

**development.json**

```
{ "name": "My Express App - Development", "mail": { "host": "dev-mail-server" } }
```

**production.json**

```
{ "name": "My Express App - Production", "mail": { "host": "prod-mail-server" } }
```

**Command Prompt Test**

If I open a command window and enter:

```
SET NODE_ENV=development
node app.js
```

I get the output:

```
Application Name: My Express App - Development
Mail Server: dev-mail-server
```

If I type:

```
SET NODE_ENV=production
node app.js
```

I get the output:

```
Application Name: My Express App - Production
Mail Server: prod-mail-server
```

**Powershell Test**

If I open a Powershell window and enter:

```
$env:NODE_ENV="development"
node app.js
```

I get the output:

```
Application Name: My Express App - Development
Mail Server: dev-mail-server
```

If I enter:

```
$env:NODE_ENV="production"
node app.js
```

I get the output:

```
Application Name: My Express App - Production
Mail Server: prod-mail-server
```

Likewise

Comment: I'm really sorry for the late reply. This totally solved my problem. I didn't know that I have been using windows powershell all this time. Thank you kind sir!

Comment: No problemo @PritzEstrada, thank you for testing my answer, have a lovely day!!